# No database selected error using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I´m trying to do my connection to my database using PDO but I´m having this error: **No database selected**.

I was reading how to use here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and I think everyting is correct.

With the old way, everything is working fine, but with PDO I have that error.

Somebody there with PDO exprience knows What I´m doing wrong?

**old way:**

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','db_name');

$connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die('Error: <strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');
$db = mysql_select_db('db_name') or die('Error<strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');
?>
```

**Now I´m trying with PDO:**

```
<?php
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUser = 'root';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbName = 'db_name';

    try
      {
        $dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbHost};dbname={$dbName}", $dbUser, $dbPass);

      }

    catch(PDOException $e)
      {
         echo $e->getMessage(); 
      }

        ?>
```

In the php file that Im using the connect.php I´m doing the include like this:

```
include('../crud/connection.php'); **//its the file with the connection**
```

And in this file that I´m using connection.php I´m doing a select statement with pdo for a login system.

I can use pdo to make the connection and then use normal sql statements right?

My idea is also turn my sql normal statments to PDO, but now that I did the connection with PDO I want test if its working so then I´ll try to pass my select statment to pdo select statment!

**My code for login:**

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['sendLogin']))
            {
                $f['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
                $f['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);




                if(!$f['email'] || !valMail($f['email']))  
                {
                  echo 'Email empty or invalid';
                }

                else if(strlen($f['pass']) <8 || strlen($f['pass'])>12)
                {
                    echo 'pass must have between 8 and 12 chars!';
                }

                else
                {
                    $autEmail = $f['email'];
                    $autpass = $f['pass'];
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users where email= '$autEmail'";       

                    $exeqr = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    $assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeqr);

                if(mysql_num_rows($exeqr) == 1 )
                {

                    if($autEmail == $assoc['email'] && $autpass == $assoc['pass'])
                    {
                        $_SESSION['assoc'] = $assoc;
                        header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        echo ' wrong answer';
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'email does no exist';
                }

                }
            }
```

**My html**

```
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
            <label>
                <span>E-mail:</span>
                <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($f['email'])) echo $f['email']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Pass:</span>
                <input type="password" class="radius" name="senha" value="<?php if(isset($f['senha'])) echo $f['senha']; ?>" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sendLogin" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're defining those variables outside of the `<?php` block, is that the problem?

Comment: No..sorry! I put that wrong when I was formating the question here. Sorry!

Comment: Is the mysql server running?

Comment: And with the old way is working correctly!

Comment: Do you get that error already when making the connection, in one of the lines of code shown – or somewhere later in your script …?

Comment: When I do the connection its ok! It gives the error when I submit my login form!

Comment: Can you please provide the piece of code on the login form where the error is encountered? The dan looks correct. You are probably using it wrong.

Comment: yes..I´ll update my question..just a minute!

Comment: Wait, are you making a connection with PDO and then continuing to use the `mysql_` functions e.g. `mysql_query()`?

Comment: @Marty Certainly appears that way

Comment: @Phil I posted that comment just before the OP made an update that made it obvious.

Comment: @Marty Crystal ball operating at peak efficiency I see ;-)

Comment: @Phil Not sure if sarcasm..

Comment: Ok, I suggest that you should copy the code of "Example #1" from this URL: php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php and change it with your host name and your database name. This will help you to find out where the problem exactly. If it's work then that's mean the problem with your php code and if not that will mean the problem is somewhere else, maybe your php installation or MySQL server. However you should double check for correct database name. I hope this will help –

Comment: @Marty Added *winky* face for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the mysql_ functions together with PDO. If you do want to execute the query you have there you have to use something like this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Example from your question:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users where email = :email';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array(':email' => $autEmail));
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that. But in pdo to do the same I was doing with assoc to acess the fields of the users, in PDO this is the substitute: $sth->execute(array(':email' => $autEmail));?

Comment: For example I´m doing my way like this now: $searchEmail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email=:email");   
     $searchEmail->bindValue(":email,$autEmail");   
     $searchEmail->execute;

Comment: That depends what you do with the statement afterwards. I suggest taking a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php.

Comment: Thank you..I was seeing that and I´m trying to convert my old sql to pdo in my way..but its giving some errors. Maybe I´ll post other question but for now I´m still trying alone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$dbName};host={$dbHost}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I go the same error! I really dont understand why this error is happening!!

Comment: Ok, I suggest that you should copy the code of "Example #1" from this URL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php and change it with your host name and your database name. This will help you to find out where the problem exactly. If it's work then that's mean the problem with your php code and if not that will mean the problem is somewhere else, maybe your php installation or MySQL server. However you should double check for correct database name. I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
  <?php
        $dbHost = 'localhost';
        $dbUser = 'root';
        $dbPass = '';
        $dbName = 'db_name';

        try
          {
            $dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbHost};dbname={$dbName}", $dbUser, $dbPass);

          }

        catch(PDOException $e)
          {
             echo $e->getMessage(); 
          }

            ?>
```

Try this

```
 <?php 
define('DB_host', 'localhost');
define('DB_username', 'root'); 
define('DB_password','');
define('DB_name','');

         try
           {
             $dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_host.";dbname=".DB_name,DB_username,DB_password);

           }

         catch(PDOException $e)
          {
             echo $e->getMessage(); 
           }

            ?>
```

OK AS PER PHIL'S Statement I will suggest that just make sure that your database is existing.. I've tried using your code and it worked on my end.. =)

Comment: This is no different (functionally) to the OP's code

Comment: Your right @Phil Thanks for pointing it out.. 
John23 just consider using my answer but your code is working just make sure that your database is existing on your end =)

Answer (score -2):

You are mixing mysql functions with PDO functions. You need to do the following:

1. Keep the mysql functions
2. Change all of your code to reflect PDO functions. This includes all mysql_* functions.

If it is something easy to do I recommend #2, else keep it #1 unless you have another reason for the switch.

Comment: Why would you recommend this?

Comment: @Phil That isn't enough of a reason IMO. If it is working fine, no need to make the change.

Comment: @Marty Many actually do. A company that has invested millions on a codebase will not go around changing, retesting, redeploying just because something becomes deprecated. Too risky.

Comment: Actually, I have a few friends starting out at companies whose role is to do exactly that, rebuild existing infrastructure using modern tools and concepts.

Comment: @AzizSaleh The *mysql* extension is also unmaintained and suffers from some large security holes.

Comment: @Marty Some companies will do, not saying they all won't. However, most companies I worked with will kill you before you try to make a change in existing working technology (even if it is outdated). If you have the resources and are willing to go through the entire process to develop your application, that is something good and should be done. However, most stake holders don't view things that way.

Comment: @Phil I don't disagree with you. However, the idea that you should change existing working code to cover something that could easily be covered with a wrapper isn't something that most companies will flow with. Mysql_ functions are not maintained anymore, however in regards to security holes, that is something I am not aware of and would love if you can share a resource in that regards.

Comment: @AzizSaleh I was more referring to the lack of prepared statements. String escaping is simply not a viable security measure against SQL injection. The deprecated extension is also way behind on updates to the MySQL server and client platforms.

Comment: @Phil I totally agree with you in that regards. Chances are if someone is not escaping their input correctly in mysql_* (not enough experience to do so) and start with PDO/MySQLI they will not use prepared statements but the same old bad coding habits of using *query() with no escaping.